# Display Azure Blob Image in dynamically created ImageButton control using CodeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

My images seem to be retrieved ok and the image buttons generate. I am not getting any Exceptions, but the 3 images are not displaying.

I commented out `"base host" +` because the value assigned to `url` didnt look right with it in the debugging watch, but no change.

```
    // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureImagesConnection"].ConnectionString);
    // Create the blob client.
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    // Retrieve a reference to a container.
    var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("usercontainer-" + AcNo.Text).ListBlobs();
    // Retrieve filenames from container List
    var urls = new List<string>();
    foreach (var blob in container)
     {
            string url = /*"base host" + */blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
            urls.Add(url);

           ImageButton imgBtn = new ImageButton();
           imgBtn.ImageUrl = url.ToString();
           imgBtn.Click += (source, args) =>
            {
                      // TBC
            };                   
            Panel1.Controls.Add(imgBtn);
}
```

Below you can see that the 3 images from the container are not displaying:

[image: Images not displaying on web page]

Comment: Is the blob container flagged as being public?  If you hit the Uri from a browser, does the image display?

Comment: Perfect, I changed the access settings and will change my code to set it on creation of the container. Thanks!